# Below is my code of create action which is not working And I have checked my database edmx file and all but still it's not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I am creating Employee registration  form. I have stored UserName ,Password and Role field in Login table and address, phon no. and as shown below details in employee table. As per my knowledge I have tried all efforts but this create method is not working... Please  help me

```
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var search = db.Logins.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserEmail == model.UserEmail);
                if (search != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Email you've enter is used by someone else. Reenter please";
                }
                else
                {
                    Login login = new Login
                    {
                        UserEmail = model.UserEmail,
                        UserPass = (model.UserPass),
                        RoleID = 2,
                        Created = DateTime.Now,


                        IsVerified = true
                    };
                    db.Logins.Add(login);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    DivineDemo.Employee emp = new DivineDemo.Employee
                    {
                        EmpID = login.UserID,
                        EmpName = model.EmpName,
                        Address = model.Address,
                        CityID = model.CityID,
                        PhoneNo = model.PhonNo,
                        Gender = model.Gender
                        //JoinDate = DateTime.Now
                    };
                    db.Employees.Add(emp);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    ViewBag.Message = "Employee added successfully";
                    ModelState.Clear();
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me to solve out my problem?

Comment: Not working ? Why do you think so ? Did you put a breakpoint and see whether the code is executing with the expected values ?

Answer (score 0):

I found my ans by examining the locals from debug. Modelstate.isvalid method was turned to false thatsway values are not inserted in db